# rosserial fails when using sensor_msgs::Imu

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to send IMU messages to ROS from an Arduino and was making good progress until last night... I can send all sorts of primitive messages, and messages which contain other primitives, but for some reason the IMU message doesn't make it to rostopic echo /imu. Code attached, please advise:

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1381881252.718444] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1381881252.726693] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [WallTime: 1381881255.329399] Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes
[INFO] [WallTime: 1381881255.329896] Setup publisher on imu [sensor_msgs/Imu]
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1381881272.931531] Mismatched protocol version in packet: lost sync or rosserial_python is from different ros release than the rosserial client
[INFO] [WallTime: 1381881272.931971] Protocol version of client is Rev 0 (rosserial 0.4 and earlier), expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
```

...

```
genpy.message.DeserializationError: unpack requires a string argument of length 32
```

Which is thrown from this line of _Imu.py:

```
(_x.orientation.x, _x.orientation.y, _x.orientation.z, _x.orientation.w,) = _struct_4d.unpack(str[start:end])
```

Here's my sketch code:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;
sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
ros::Publisher pub("imu", &imu_msg);
char frame_id[] = "imu";

void setup(){  
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub);
  
  imu_msg.header.seq = 0;
  imu_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
  imu_msg.header.frame_id = frame_id;
  
  
  imu_msg.orientation.x = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation.y = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation.z = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation.w = 0;
  
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[0] = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[1] = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[2] = 0;
  
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[3] = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[4] = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[5] = 0;
  
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[6] = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[7] = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[8] = 0;
  
  
  imu_msg.angular_velocity.x = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = 0;
  
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[0] = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[1] = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[2] = 0;
  
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[3] = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[4] = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[5] = 0;
  
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[6] = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[7] = 0;
  imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[8] = 0;
  
  
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = 0;
  
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[0] = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[1] = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[2] = 0;
  
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[3] = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[4] = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[5] = 0;
  
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[6] = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[7] = 0;
  imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[8] = 0;
}

void loop(){
  
  imu_msg.header.seq++;
  imu_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
  
  // Doesn't work:
  pub.publish(&imu_msg);
  
  // These work:
  // pub.publish(&imu_msg.header);
  // pub.publish(&imu_msg.orientation);
  // pub.publish(&imu_msg.angular_velocity);
  
  // This doesn't
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(500);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91301/rosserial-fails-when-using-sensor_msgs::imu/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [colidar](https://answers.ros.org/users/42343/colidar/) on 2019-07-23**:
thanks for sharing your sketch code, it helped me a lot. But why is it working with setting every value to zero? Because of that the imu_message is literally empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IMU message is too large for the Arduino serial port buffer:
http://answers.ros.org/question/12782/rosserial_arduino-cant-send-a-sensor_msgsimu-msg/

The solution is to send a float array via serial and then convert that to an IMU message in another node.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on 2016-11-13**:
got the same error while trying to receive from arduino

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2016-11-13**:
Depending on your board (UNO/M0/...) you can search for the define #define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 64" in the arduino framework and increase it :-)
Look for a file named RingBuffer.h